# android - get textview ID as string

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

I have the following XML TextView layout:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/txt0027_PDY911"
    android:tag="canPlot"
    style="@style/STD_Block_BEL.FieldLabel"
    android:text="0.00" />
```

which has a onTouch() event bound.

In the onTouch() I need to obtain the textview's id (*txt0027_PDY911*) as string in order to run a query with it.
**getId()** returns an integer - how can I get the string?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need the Id as a String? the Id is supposed to be used to only retrieve the `TextView` element....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `getResources().getResourceEntryName(getId())` or `getResources(). getResourceName(getId())`. The former returns the entry name for a given id. The latter returns the full name for a given id. This name is a single string of the form `"package:type/entry"`.

Answer (score 1):

you can try :

```
text.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch (View v, MotionEvent event) {
                ...
                String id= v.getResources().getResourceName(v.getId());
            }

        });
```