# Recyclerview radio button group get the checked radio

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-radiogroup

I have the following in my recylerview row item

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/radioItems"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="2"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_yes"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.8"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="Yes"/>
            <RadioButton android:id="@+id/radio_no"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="No"/>
        </RadioGroup>
```

So i want in my recyclerview adapter to listen when the radiogroup item is checked and get whether its yes or no which has been checked.SO in my recyclerview on bindviewholder i have

```
      holder.radioItems.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) {
            Log.i("test",""+group.getCheckedRadioButtonId());
        }
    });
```

But when i check on my log i can see values like `2131230980, 2131230979` but not the id of the the radio button

I expected to see the id of `radio_yes` or `radio_no` in the log.
What am i missing out on this.
I still want to use radiogroup rather than independent radio buttons.

Comment: `2131230980` and `2131230979` are the ids of the radio buttons.

Comment: I want to get the id name as set on the radio buttons that is radio_yes and no respectively

Answer (score 0):

you can see this answer 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/29818783/5523669

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(getId())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a switch case to find the current checked Id  in **setOnCheckedChangeListener**

```
       switch (checkedId) {
            case R.id.radio_yes :
              Log.i("test","radio_no");
             break;
             case R.id.radio_no:
              Log.i("test","radio_yes");
             break;

        }
```

or simpler than switch case you can  use below code

```
String currentCheckedId=getResources().getResourceEntryName(checkedId);
Log.d("test",currentCheckedId);
```